# Is there a way to list all the fibonacci numbers in a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci, python-3.7

I just started learning python and trying to list all fibonacci numbers to nth term. I have written some code which I think is on the right track but I'm confused on where to go next

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    l = [0,1]
    for i in range(2,n)
         fibonacci(i-1) + fibonacci(i-2)
```

The code is incomplete, I know I have to link the last line back into the earlier code but I am quite confused on where to go next. Please, can someone help?

Comment: As to your question in the title - yes a few. feel free to google fibonacci and you'll find them. As to your code - you're not using recurssion correctly, mainly missing the stopping condition, not returning anything and using a loop inside your recursion

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by missing the stopping condition? So there should be another condition after the fib(i-1) line? How is the recursion inside the loop?

Comment: I recommend you to try reading a bit about recurssion. See some examples to get the hang of it and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way of implementation. Here n is the nth term.

```
n = 25
a = 0
b = 1
print(a)
print(b)
for i in range(n-2):
  c = a + b;
  print(c)
  a = b;
  b = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in the internet will show you there are a few interesting ways for implementing fibonacci code. The main basic ones are: Iteration, and Recurssion. The problem with your code is that you kinda mixed them both together.

If you want to go with Recurssion, the main ingredients you are missing are: stopping condition and the actual step (since you're not returning anything). To use Recurssion you must make sure it will stop at some point. For this we use stopping conditions. In our case, the stopping conditions are the known values: `0` and `1`. So we will want something like:

```py
if n == 1:
    return 0
if n == 2:
    return 1
```

Now that we have the stopping condition, the rest is easy. Simply do the step and the rest will work on its own:

```py
def fib_rec(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1

    return fib_rec(n-1) + fib_rec(n-2)
```

Jump in to [this link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20fib_rec%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3D%3D%202%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%20fib_rec%28n-1%29%20%2B%20fib_rec%28n-2%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20res%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28fib_rec%285%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to see a visualization of what happens there.

---

If you want to use a loop, it is just up to working out the logic with swapping variables` values. Something like:

```py
def fib_loop(n):
    prev = 0
    cur = 1
    for _ in range(2, n):
        next = prev + cur
        prev = cur
        cur = next
    return next
```

Again, go [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20fib_loop%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20prev%20%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20cur%20%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20for%20_%20in%20range%282,%20n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next%20%3D%20prev%20%2B%20cur%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prev%20%3D%20cur%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cur%20%3D%20next%0A%20%20%20%20return%20next%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28fib_loop%285%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) to see a visualization of the code. Will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

A generator which (conceptually) provides *all* of them lets the user decide how many to take:

```
def fibonacci():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

from itertools import slice

first_ten = list(islice(fibonacci(), 10))
first_twenty = list(islice(fibonacci(), 20))
# etc
```